# I can't get character from user in python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a script reads path from user, When i used `input()` and `raw_input()` to get character from user

```
choice = raw_input()
    if choice[0] is 'y' or 'Y':
        print ("text")
    else:
        print ("another text")
```

and press *y* or any key, The console shows *text* in the if condition.
I changed the `choice[0]` to `choice` and the problem still exist.

Comment: use `input()` instead of `raw_input()`

Comment: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/untitled/checker.py", line 31, in <module>
    choice = input()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'n' is not defined

@ArpitSolanki

Comment: did you define any variable n which you are using?

Comment: No. also appear when i replaced n with any character except 'y'. @ArpitSolanki

Comment: post the full code then

Comment: [Full Code](https://github.com/zeyadetman/RemoveDuplicateFiles/blob/master/main.py)

@ArpitSolanki

Comment: @ZeyadEtman check answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:-

```
choice = input()
if choice[0] == 'y' or choice[0] == 'Y':
    print('text')
else:
    print('another text')
```

I am using python 3.6.1 and it work for me. It may be help you.
raw_input() was renamed to input() in later version 3.

Comment: i get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/untitled/checker.py", line 31, in <module>
    choice = input()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'n' is not defined

here's my [Full code](https://github.com/zeyadetman/RemoveDuplicateFiles/blob/master/main.py)

Comment: why you did not use this if choice[0] == 'y' or choice[0] == 'Y'  instead of if choice[0] is 'y' or 'Y' and why use somewhere raw_input() or input(). Please check and run my code separately it will work fine.

Comment: Refresh the page. @S_sauden

Comment: I run your script in another file but i get same error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/untitled1/fff.y.py", line 1, in <module>
    choice = input()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'n' is not defined

@S_sauden

Comment: if you use version 2.7.x raw_input() work finely or if you use version 3.x version input() work fine. My code work fine to me.